# Protect my Django REST API (basic Authentication or anything else)

Tags: django, api, rest, basic-authentication

I'm trying to protect my Django restful api.
I got two clients :

- my Django Front end application (Ajax requests on my server)
- a python application using httplib to make its own requests

For now I'm using HTTP Basic Authentication to allow a client to consume a resource.
A basic username/password on a auth method managing a cookie session.
In production I ensure that my API is only available over https.

I tried to implement HMAC construction (because I don't want to put my password on the wire, but I have to store the secret at both ends). This work well with my other python application, but not with my Django Front end application since any user can see the javascript code.

I tried to implement an other authentication method because I don't want to really maintain a session state (not really REST).

```
curl -H "PERSONAL_SECRET_API_KEY: TokenKeyxxxxxxxxxx" https://localhost:8000/api/resource/
```

Here my questions:

- **What are the weaknesses of the basic Authentication System ?**
- **Is there another method which suit my purposes ?**

Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at http://django-rest-framework.org/ provides a lot of great authentication options and could help you focus on the other parts of your app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Being prone to repeat attack is in my opinion the largest weakness of basic authentication.
2. Have you considered public/private key infrastructure? Client apps create public/private key pairs. Public keys are stored on the server. Client app encrypts its request with private key, server can decrypt it with client app's public key and send the response the same way.

Comment: 1. so if i use CSRF token I'm protected from replay attack ? 2. 'Client app encrypts its request with private key' < I can't do this on javascript side without showing my private key ? am I wrong ?

Comment: 1. If someone forges a CSRF token together with capturing username and password then you are still vulnerable. 2. You're right. In this case it won't work.